# How can I test individual speakers on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, speakers

The MacBook Pro 2019 has 6 built-in speakers. Is there some way I can test them 1 at a time? All I can find is how to test left side or right side independently, or how to run [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) which I'm not convinced will detect degraded audio from 1 of the speakers.

Comment: Apps>Utilities>Audio MIDI Setup [device>output] - Do they show as 5.1 or Stereo? If they show as 5.1 then in Configure Speakers… clicking any 'speaker' will play a white noise sound from that one only. Only trouble with white noise is it probably won't be easy to tell by ear which device is distorting. If they show as only Stereo with no option to change in the Configuration drop-menu, then isolating one is likely not possible.

Comment: If you suspect a hardware problem with a new machine, then you should take it to an Apple Store or wherever you purchased it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, the speakers show up as stereo, no option for any other configuration.

Comment: You should go ahead and run apple diagnostics. You may not trust it if it says no problem found but if it reports an error or degradation with a speaker then something is probably wrong.